# app won't work with any iOS other than 9.1.3

Tags: ios

I just made my first iOS app and my friends running old firmware (9.1.1) cant download it.  When they try to download it they get a popup that says they need to upgrade to iOS 9.1.3 does anyone know why it would do this and how I could make it work with older iOS versions?

Comment: Is this an App Store app? What does iTunes Connect show as the minimum iOS version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things that you can do here :

- Deployment target to the minimum version you support
- MinimumOSVersion key value in Info.plist file

[image]

Comment: thank you! whats the lowest ios you recommend supporting?

Comment: Personally, I always go for 7.1 but up to you what kind of audience you are targeting.

Comment: please accept it as answer if it helped you sorting out the issue.

Comment: thank you! sorry i didnt know i could do that.. new to the whole stackoverflow thing